# How to filter the object from array by using id and display the required value from redux array to original array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have an array like this... and this is from the redux store

```
cart : [
_id: 1248
name:"capsules"
quantity:5
price:250
]
```

This is my original array from which iam adding items to cart (redux array)

```
productArray : [
_id: 1248
name:"capsules"
quantity:1
price:250
]   
     .... (many more, i'am using mapping for it)
```

The scenario is that if I click on add to cart, then the quantity in cart page changes like given above(redux array) but not in original array while paralleley updating the quantity in the home page with + nd - buttons.
How to filter the cart array and match the id so that if the quantity changes there, it should also change in the home page with (productArray).

I have done something like this ..,

```
updateCart= (id) =>{
cart.filter(item=>{
    if(item._id===id){
return item.quantity (i know this is wrong)
//dont know how to return the quantity//
               }
       }
}
```

This is the JSX for homepage:

```
return(
 {productArray.map(item => {
                            item.quantity = 1;
                            return (
                                <div  key={item._id}>
                                    <div className="product-details">
                                        <div>{item.name}</div>
                                        <div>{item.price}</div>
                                        <div className="quantity">
                                             <p>updateCart(item._id) <p>
                                               </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>    
                                 </div>
```

I have added the increase and decrease quantity functionality for the cart array and would like to fetch it to the original array using the updateCart() method !!

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using redux and you have stored your state in the redux store, then you will have to update the state stored in the redux store. To update the state in the store, you need to make use of actions and dispatch method to trigger the action. you might have to make 2 actions to add and to remove from cart. It might look like this

```js
const AddItemAction=(cart) => ({
  type: "ADD_ITEM",
  value: cart
});

const removeItem =(id) => ({
  type: "REMOVE_ITEM",
  value: id
});
```

Then in your reducer, you will need to handle this action types. you normally do like

```js
const reducer = (action, state) =>{
 switch(action.type){
   case:"ADD_ITEM": 
    return {...state, cart: [...state.cart, action.value]};
   
   case:"REMOVE_ITEM":
    const filterd = state.cart.filter(x=> x.id !== action.value);
    return {...statte, cart: filtered };
   
   default:
    return state;
 }

}
```